# When I use Drilldown(Highcharts), My build --prod becomes very large in angular 8

Tags: angular, dictionary, highcharts

I used lazy loading in the project. Everything works fine as long as I use the  Drilldown(Highcharts).
In this case, when I get the build from the project, the module in which Drilldown, is loaded first and the **main.js** file size becomes very large.

I used Highcharts to show the world map and I used this method to show the province of each country when it is clicked.

```
 createDrillDownCountry(data: any, chart: any) {
        const country = data.drilldown,
            mapKey = 'countries/' + country + '/' + country + '-all',
            mapData = require(`@highcharts/map-collection/${mapKey}.geo.json`),
            provinceData = Highcharts.geojson(mapData);
        provinceData.forEach((el: any, i) => {
            if (el.properties['hc-key'] === this.divisionsManagementService.currentDivision) {
                el.selected = true;
            }
            if (Object.keys(this.allDivisions).length > 0 && this.allDivisions[country]) {
                for (let index = 0; index < this.allDivisions[country].length; index++) {
                    if (this.allDivisions[country][index].prefix === el.properties['hc-key']) {
                        el.centerData = this.allDivisions[country][index];
                        el.value = i * 10;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        el.value = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(data, {
            name: data.name,
            data: provinceData,
            events: {
                click: (event) => {
                    if (this.addMode) {
                        if (event.point.value === 0 || event.point.value === undefined) {
                            this.clickedOnMap.emit(event);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (event.point.value > 0) {
                            this.clickedOnMap.emit(event);
                        } else {
                            this.clickedOnMap.emit(false);
                            this.openAddPage.emit(event);
                            this.divisionsManagementService.currentDivision = event.point.properties['hc-key'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            allowPointSelect: true,
            states: {
                select: {
                    color: '#cadbff',
                    borderColor: '#9a9a9a',
                    dashStyle: 'dash'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        });
    }
```

Interesting if I delete this method. Lazy loading works properly. But if I use this method. The module is loaded from the beginning.

Comment: You used the world map chart. You used a drill to show the provinces.
So far right? Does not work  lazy when build?

Comment: Where do you fire that method?

Comment: I fire it in ngOnInit() from lazy module

Comment: this happens only in production builds?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
 mapData = require(`@highcharts/map-collection/${mapKey}.geo.json`)
```

with

```
import(`@highcharts/map-collection/${mapKey}.geo.json`).then((response) => {
           const provinceData = Highcharts.geojson(response);
}
```